# selenium - want to select all values from second column in a table

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have this table:

https://investing.thisismoney.co.uk/market-data/risers-fallers/

I want my selenium script to select all the epics

I have tried the code below which fails to print anything.

```
epic = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/article/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td').text
```

I am fairly new to selenium and have not been able to identify how I go about getting all the values in the epic column. Can someone kindly help

Comment: The XPath is probably incorrect, no? Are you familiar with XPath? Also, please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps:

```
1) Create xpath to reach each cell from where have to get Text:
epics = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'pricesGLTable')]//tr/td[3]")

2) Make a loop to iterate for every row to get the Text:
   for epic in epics:

3) Print from text into loop,
   print(epic.text)
```

For Expample:

```
epics = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'pricesGLTable')]//tr/td[3]")
 for epic in epics:
 print(epic.text)
```

Please try these steps and let me know...

Answer (score 1):

Try with this code:

```
epics = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[2]/article/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[3]')

for epic in epics:
    text = epic.text
    print(text)
```

EDIT 2 : Your code isn't working because your xpath is incorrect.
It is retrieving all the columns, and not only the second from the left (the epic column), as the xpath i wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a relative XPath expression and the appropriate method `driver.find_elements`

```
epics = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'pricesGLTable')]//tr/td[3]")
list = ''
for label in epics:
   list += label.text
   print (list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below css selector to get the list of values in epic column and iterate over it to print the text:

```
   epics = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("table[class^='pricesGLTable'] tr td:nth- 
   child(3)")
   for epic in epics:
   print(epic.text)
```